# Action not visible in page layout setup

Tags: salesforce, action, salesforce-lightning, lwc, page-layout

I have created an action to show a *lightning component* on the contact record:

[image]

When I go to the page layout editor I am not able to see the button to add to the page layout.

I tried with *global action* but that also doesn't seem to be working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to see the button in **Mobile & Lightning Actions** in the Page Layout Edit page